# How do you move an object in a wavy pattern?

Tags: java

I know the following code will move an object in a straight line. How can I get the object to travel in a wavy line? I know that something extra is required for the `x` variable.

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g) 
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval ((int) (x - r), (int) (y - r), (int)
                    (2 * r),
                    (int) (2 * r));

            y++;


            if (y - r > height)
                y = -r;
        }
```

Comment: Could you upload a picture of how you want it to move?

Comment: Here is an URL which shows the pattern: http://rookery.s3.amazonaws.com/1772500/1772658_76cb_625x625.jpg

Comment: Sine or cosine should produce that pattern.

Comment: I have used y++;
     x-=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(50)); but this simply changes the object direction while its moving. A consist left to right movement is what I am after.

Comment: See my edited answer. (y and x can be swapped to change the axis of movement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the sine or cosine function to calculate y as a function of x.

Multiply the sine or cosine function to increase the amplitude (how high it goes)

```
y = 100 * sin(x) // will make it have peaks of -100 and 100
```

Divide the x to increase the period. (distance between peaks)

```
y = sin(x/2) // will make it take twice the x distance between peaks.
```

Something like this:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g) 
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval ((int) (x - r), (int) (y - r), (int)
                (2 * r),
                (int) (2 * r));

        x++; // Left to right movement
        // Example, modify the multipliers as necessary
        y = 100 * Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(x/4))
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks, much appreciated! My solution was y++ (object dropping downwards), and x += 10*Math.sin(y/5);

Answer (score 2):

Including a sin(x) or cos(x) in your function will provide a regular wave pattern, irregular pattern needs a more sophisticated function

Comment: Hi, Can you advise how to apply this into the code? I have already attempted to use Math.sin(x) and Math.cos(x) but a steady wavy line is not showing on screen.

Comment: so you want the line to be wavy but irregularly wavy?
Then I would add a Random variable that inflicts the amplitude of the wave.

Comment: It does not matter how wavy the object movement is. I want to be able to see the object change directions (from left to right) in a wavy pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure where the motion is taking place in your code. Never worked with animations in java. But if you integrate a sine function where x is a variable that loops a value from -pi to pi you will have a wave as the product of that when plotted. Be aware that the product from a sine or cosine function always is between -1 and 1 so you may have to multiply it to actually show it as a wavy movement in your animation, i.e. -1 and 1 may be too small of a value to actually make a visible impact of the movement

Answer (score 2):

I know you already accepted an answer, but here's something to draw additional inspiration from that I whipped up...

```
package wavy;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Wavy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wavy!");

        final WavyPanel wp = new WavyPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(wp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Ticker t = new Ticker(wp);
        final Repainter r = new Repainter(wp);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        final Timer tickTimer = new Timer();
        final Timer paintTimer = new Timer();

        paintTimer.schedule(r, 1000, 50);
        tickTimer.schedule(t, 1000, 10);

    }

    private static class WavyPanel extends JPanel {

        private final Dimension size = new Dimension(640, 480);
        private int amplitude = 50;
        private int frequency = 5;

        private int x = 0;
        private double y = size.height / 2;
        private int yBase = 0;

        WavyPanel() {

            super(true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {

            final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fillOval(x, (int)y, 30, 30);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void tick() {

            //Move a pixel to the right; loop over to the left when reaching edge
            x = (++x) % size.width;

            //Length of one full wave = panel width divided by frequency
            final int waveLength = size.width / frequency;

            //Incrementing yBase; capping off at wavelength
            yBase = (++yBase) % waveLength;

            //Normalizing to [0..1]
            final double normalized = (double)yBase / (double)waveLength;

            //Full wave at 2*pi, means...
            final double radians = normalized * Math.PI * 2;

            //Getting the sine
            final double sine = Math.sin(radians);

            //Multiplying with amplitude, add to center position and we have our y
            y = (int)(sine * amplitude) + size.height/2;

        }

    }

    private static class Ticker extends TimerTask {

        private final WavyPanel panel;

        Ticker(final WavyPanel panel) {

            this.panel = panel;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            panel.tick();

        }

    }

    private static class Repainter extends TimerTask {

        private final WavyPanel panel;

        Repainter(final WavyPanel panel) {

            this.panel = panel;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            panel.repaint();

        }

    }

}
```

This should run at an approximate 20 frames per second. You can increase this by setting the second argument of `paintTimer.schedule(r, 1000, 50)` lower. The speed of movement can be altered by lowering (speeding up) or increasing (slower) the second argument of `tickTimer.schedule(t, 1000, 50)`.

Changing the `amplitude` field of WavyPanel will change how high/low the circle moves. Changing the `frequency` to a higher value will result in shorter waves, while a lower value will produce longer waves.

With some additional work you could add in controls to change the amplitude and frequency on-the-fly. Some additional notes:

- You may wish to add some safeguard to the `tick()` method to make sure that when one invocation is already running, additional ones are skipped until the first one is done. Otherwise the calculations could fail for short tick intervals. A semaphore could be used here.
- Since trigonometric calculations aren't exactly the cheapest, you may consider caching some results (e.g. in an array) for re-use if many similar animations are to be played or if there's a lot more drawing going on.

Comment: I salute you! This produces a perfect wave! I suck at math, and you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm interpreting this right. Could use the sine or cosine of either your x or y coordinate. I'm not at a machine with java so I can't make an example at the moment..

Comment: How would you apply a sine or cosine function into this code? Adding something like x-=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(50)); only changes direction of the object one way. One want a consist movement from left and right. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If you want it to go left to right, you need to increment your x variable.

Comment: Check user1071777's answer! Sorry for being brief

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you need to update both the x and y variables to get a wavy line. Here's the general strategy for a horizontal line that is wavy up and down:

1. Choose a function f(x) that has the shape you want. This will be used to calculate values for y. (For instance, you can use `y = amplitude * Math.sin(frequency * x)` to get a regular sine wave of a given amplitude and frequency.)
2. If necessary, write the code that implements your function.
3. Set x to some initial value.
4. In `draw`, before you paint the oval, calculate `y = f(x);`. Paint the oval and then increment `x`. If necessary, reset `x` so it stays in range.

If you want a vertical line that is wavy left and right, just reverse the roles of `x` and `y` in the above. If you want the oval to go in the reverse direction, just decrement instead of increment in step 4.

Answer (score 0):

this sample is for point(Line with one length) on sinus graph and clock using.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class RunSwing extends JPanel {
    static int x1 = 500;
    static int y1 = 500;
    static int x2 = x1;
    static int y2 = y1;
    final static int vectorLength = 100;
    final static int sinx2 = x2;
    final static int siny2 = y2;
    static double count = 0;
    private static RunSwing run = new RunSwing();

    final Timer print = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            //increaseSinusGraph();
            increaseClockVector();
            count+=6; //for clock for 1 second
            /*count++;//for sinus*/
            if (count % 360 == 0)
                System.out.println((count / 360) + " minute passed");
        }
    });


    RunSwing() {
        print.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("amir");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(run);
        frame.setSize(1100, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static void increaseClockVector() {
        double cos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(count));
        double sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(count));
        y2 = siny2 + (int) (vectorLength * sin);
        x2 = sinx2 + (int) (vectorLength * cos);
    }

    static void increaseSinusGraph() {
        double sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(count));
        y2 = siny2 + (int) (vectorLength * sin);
        x2++;
    }

    private void createPoint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawLine(x2, y2, x2 + 1, y2 + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);//for clock
        /*g.drawLine(x2, y2, x2+1, y2+1);//for sinus*/
        repaint();
    }
}
```